Discord bot is online - but not responding
I created a discord bot with replit in js. The bot has only one command, its to say pong when we say ping.
Here is my code:
require('dotenv').config(); // Assurez-vous que le fichier .env est chargé

const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
  ]
});

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("Discord bot is online!");
});

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  // Log des messages reçus pour déboguer
  console.log(`Received message: '${message.content}'`);

  // Ignore les messages envoyés par le bot lui-même
  if (message.author.bot) {
    console.log("Message is from a bot. Ignoring.");
    return;
  }

  console.log("Message is not from a bot.");

  const trimmedMessage = message.content.trim();
  console.log(`Trimmed message: '${trimmedMessage}'`);

  const lowercaseMessage = trimmedMessage.toLowerCase();
  console.log(`Lowercase message: '${lowercaseMessage}'`);

  if (lowercaseMessage === "ping") {
    console.log("Received 'ping' message.");
    message.channel.send("pong").then(() => {
      console.log("Sent 'pong' in response to 'ping'");
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error("Failed to send 'pong':", err);
    });
  } else {
    console.log(`Message content '${lowercaseMessage}' is not 'ping'.`);
  }
});

// Connexion au bot Discord
client.login(process.env.token).catch(err => {
  console.error("Failed to login:", err);
});

I just wanted to do that and its created with chatgpt.
It's supposed to say pong in the discord channel but nothing appears and the console says

Message content is not 'ping'


Does your bot have the necessary permissions to send messages?

Your code works perfectly fine, the most likely possibility is that you forgot to also enable the message content intent in the application priviledged gateway intents, as well as in your client intents.
To do this, go to the discord developer applications page, select your bot, and enable the message content intent setting.
